# YouTube embedded videos are "not playable on the server", while the application "works fine on localhost"

Tags: angular, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to play some videos using YouTube's api in an angular application and I am using "youtube-player": "^5.5.0" npm package.

The application runs fine on the localhost where it can play all the videos, when deployed on to server, most of the sample videos are not working.

As the videos are playable YouTube website as well as on localhost, I am not sure what I am missing here, I don't see any warnings on dev tools either.

For example here is the sample video id: vlkNcHDFnGA,  I can also see that videos are playable on iframe directly: https://jsfiddle.net/skjagini/419wcuod/

I can confirm that the videos are embeddable and syndicated, here is the query I am issuing to find the results

```
YouTubeService youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "key",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = searchText; 
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 5; // 50
            searchListRequest.Type = "video";
            searchListRequest.VideoSyndicated = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoSyndicatedEnum.True__;
            searchListRequest.VideoEmbeddable = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoEmbeddableEnum.True__;
```

In .html file I have

```
<section class="app-footer footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <span class="float-left">
            <div class="player-defaults" id="video-player"></div>
        </span>
```

In .ts file I have

```
this.player = YouTubePlayer('video-player', {
    height: 60, width: 100
});

this.player.on('stateChange', (event) => {
    if (!this.stateNames[event.data]) {
        throw new Error('Unknown state (' + event.data + ').');
        // console.log()
    } else if (event.data === 0) {
        this.playNext();
    }
});

playVideoById(vidoeId: string) {
    if (vidoeId == null) {
        if (this.activeSong) {
            vidoeId = this.activeSong.videoId;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    this.isPlaying = true;
    // 'loadVideoById' is queued until the player is ready to receive API calls.
    this.player.loadVideoById(vidoeId); // player.loadVideoById('M7lc1UVf-VE');
    this.playVideo();
}

playVideo() {
    this.isPlaying = true;
    // 'playVideo' is queue until the player is ready to received API calls and after 'loadVideoById' has been called.
    this.player.playVideo();
}
```

Edit: When I right click on the youtube player and select embedded video, it seems to produce correct html, its the same as my JSFiddle

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vlkNcHDFnGA" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If I click on youtube logo, it opens in youtube browser and plays the video just fine.

Just not sure why it plays in JSFiddle, localhost, but not on server.

**EDIT:** I do notice that I am getting CORD (not CORS error) as my server is http while google ads service which youtube invokes behind the scenes is https. Is this could be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube IFrame expects the host to be running on https domain.

The IFrame would work just fine on localhost as localhost is considered as secure, but when hosted on public domain, it needs to be served through Https.

I have used free Certificates from LetsEncrypt to get ssl for the domain, and things started working thereafter.

Answer (score -1):

> YouTube embedded videos are “not playable on the server”

seems clear enough to me. It means the server does not support embedded videos.

Comment: Couple of videos are still playable, but the ones in question are not though they are working on localhost, they work on jsFiddle etc as said in the description.

Comment: What is the difference between videos that play and those that do not play?

Comment: @crou Here is a video id that doesn't play: vlkNcHDFnGA and the one that actually plays: YFfEFbC9_XQ, I checked that both videos are embeddable, syndicated, and there are no restrictions on US. they both are playable on jsFiddle on iFrame directly.  I am not really sure what could be causing it.